# will onDestroy() of activity always be called on application destroy?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 5 activity ex. Act 1>Act 2>Act 3>Act 4>Act 5. and each activity has ovveridden onDestroy(). Now what will happen if user on Act 5 and destroy the Application from recent Apps? Will it call onDestroy() of eachActivity?

Answer (score 3):

Generally yes, but you cannot rely 100% on this, because activities may get destroyed for other reasons. For example if the user switches to another app the system may decide to temporarily kill your activities to reclaim resources, and recreate them when the user switches back to your app. If this happens and then the user kills your app, you will not get an onDestroy() call because there is no "live" activity to destroy, they are all already dead.

Also please note that the onStop() and onDestroy() methods are not guaranteed to be called right away, they may be called some time after. The only guarantee is the order of the calls: onStop() will not be called before onPause(), and onDestroy() will not be called before onStop().

Comment: what i want to achieve is that once the user logs into my app, one service keep running (auto update) i.e Activity 1 and and keep running until i logout?

Comment: Use a service to handle things in the background, and persist important data (with SharedPreferences or save it to a file/database) so that you don't lose it if (or when) activities get destroyed, don't use an activity to keep state information.

Comment: @bikash_binay: then you have asked an X for Y question. Please edit your question or ask a new one setting out what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: yes it's generally a good idea to state exactly what is the goal, and not just ask about some specific way to do - it might be completely the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Activity Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)

*There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.*

Android apps that are killed will likely be killed based on PID (Process ID) which means the application gets killed and not the individual activites.

Comment: if system kills the process, what will happen to running services?

Comment: Services are not directly related to the application and/or activities and will run in the background until the user or the system kills them.

Comment: Your comment above is not true. `Service`s are Android components and live (generally) in the same OS process as other components (`Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`, etc.) of an application. When Android kills the OS process, it will also kill any running `Service`. Depending on how the `Service` is configured, Android may restart the `Service`.